# Restrict Contacts only related to Account that is associated to a Custom Object

Tags: lookup-filter

I am trying to restrict the users ability to Select contacts to only those related to the Account.  Here is the Structure:
On the Custom Object there is a Master-Detail(Account) lookup.  I also have a Contact Lookup field which is the one I want to filter.  I thought I could use a filter and have the it work like this: 
Sales Program: Account ID equals to Field Sales Program: Account ID.
The issue is that I do not see Sales Program: **Account ID** just Sales Program: Account.  Is this because I have the relationship of the custom object to Account is set as a Master-Details relationship?
Thanks,
M

[image: Sales Program Object with Contact field filter]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you see `Sales Program: Account` it will work as if referring to `Sales Program: Account Id`. Once you save the filter you'll see in Filter Criteria that it is saved as the Id.

I agree that this is confusing GUI by Salesforce.

So just go ahead and create the filter!

I did the same in my org and when creating the filter like this:
[image]

It ends up saving it like this (note the `ID` is added after `Site:Account`:
[image]

Comment: thanks for the reply.  my criteria is currently: Sales Program: Account equals field Account Contacts: Account ID.  This does not filter the the Contact list.  I was able to do this same process on an Activity but using the same logic is not working here.\

Comment: It works fine in my org, also in a M-D relationship to Account. Would you be able to include a screenshot of your Lookup Filter Criteria?

Comment: I have added an image of my filter configuration to the original post. Thanks,

Comment: hmm my filter looks exactly the same and works fine for me. The only thing that strikes me is the term 'Account Contacts' on your right-side parameter. Are you sure that is the right field? I'd expect a 'single' contact..

Comment: This is a custom field and I named it so that the user will know that they will only be able to search for Contacts on the Account that is associated to the Sales Program object.   Thanks, M

Comment: Holy Cow.  I did not have the filter 'enabled'.....

Comment: Thanks for all your help and patience. I am going to post another question to where the lookup displays the associated contacts for the account so the user can just in case they are not familiar with who is associated to the account.  Cheers, M

Comment: great, I knew we'd get there :-)

Answer (score 0):

I know many are facing this issue, so I was also facing the same issue, **the solution is that the particular "Sales Program" lookup of the Account should be on the same page layout**. then only it will work. actually, what happens to the lookup filter pulls data basically from UI, so if data will present on UI then only it's able to fetch the data otherwise not.